# $G(f) \le \|f\|_{H^s(\mathbb R)},\; s>2 \Rightarrow G(f) \le \|f\|_{H^2(\mathbb R)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If a quantity of a function $f$, call $G(f)$ satisfies
$$
G(f) \le \|f\|_{H^s(\mathbb R)}
$$
for all $s>2$, then can I conclude that this holds for the limiting case $s\to 2$:
$$
G(f) \le \|f\|_{H^2(\mathbb R)}
$$
as well?
Here $H^s$ denotes the usual Sobolev space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

It is possible that
$$
\|f\|_{H^s}=\infty
$$
for all $s>2$ and
$$
\|f\|_{H^2}<\infty.
$$
Take for example the function $f$, with
$$
\hat f(\xi)=\frac{1}{(1+\xi^2)^{3/2}(1+\log(\xi^2+1))}.
$$

**Note.** If $\|f\|_{H^{s_0}}<\infty$, for some $s_0>2$, then
$$
\lim_{s\searrow 2}\|f\|_{H^s}=\|f\|_{H^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, then if $\|f\|_{H^s}<\infty$ for all $s\ge 2$, then does the result above hold?

Comment: Yes it does. This is a consequence of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to consider the case when $\| f\|_{H^s}$ is infinite!

Comment: See update of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this works.

Since the function $a^x$ is convex as a function of $x$ we have, putting $a=(1+|\xi|^2)$ that

$$
(1+|\xi|^2)^r\leq (1-\theta)(1+|\xi|^2)^t +\theta (1+|\xi|^2)^s, \qquad r=(1-\theta)t+\theta s. 
$$
Multiplying both sides by $|\hat{f}|^2$ and integrating over $\mathbb{R}$ we get that the function $h(t)=\| f\|_{H^t}^2$ is convex on an interval where it's finite. In particular, it's continuous there. Your result follows from this as long as you know that $\| f\|_{H^s}$ is finite for some $s>2$ at least.